# Octave Coding - I need help coding coefficients of polynomial

Tags: matlab, octave, linear-algebra, polynomial-math

This question fairly easy doing it manually however, I am struggling to have this written in code.

There is a quartic polynomial:

```
P(x)=ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e
```

There is also a given matrix M:

```
5 0 -1 2 9
-2 -1 0 1 2
```

Which the first row gives P(x) and the second row gives the value of x.

Using the information in matrix M, find the coefficients:

a, b, c, d, e

I would know how to work this manually, subbing each column and solve simultaneously with the other columns to obtain a value for each coefficient or put it in a matrix.

I have an idea of what to do, but I don't know how to code it.

I do believe the last line would be `linearsolve(M(,1),M(,2))` and thus be able to obtain each coefficient but I have no idea how to get to that line.

Comment: I've tried
```y=M(1,:);
x=M(2,:);
a = polyval(y,x);``` already. and It gives me ```p(x) = 81*x^8 + 11*x^7 + 9*x^6 + 15*x^5 + 89*x^4 + 0*x^3 + 0*x^2 + 0*x^1 + 0```. I don't know how or why as it is supposedly suppose to be a quartic.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Andy. However, I have also tried that already polyfit(y,x,n) where n = 4 as it's the 4th degree. and I get values of 0 or very close to zero.

```p(x) = 0*x^8 + 0*x^7 + 1*x^6 + 0*x^5 - 1*x^4 + 0*x^3 + 0*x^2 + 0*x^1 + 0```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome J Cheong

```
% Values of y and x (note: in your post you had 2 values at x = 1, I assumed that was an accident)
M = [5 0 -1 2 9 ; -2 -1 0 1 2];

% Separate for clarity
y = M(1,:);
x = M(2,:);

% Fit to highest order polynomial model
f = fit(x',y',['poly', num2str(length(y)-1)])

% Extract coefficients
coeff = coeffvalues(f);

% Plotting
X = linspace(min(x)-1, max(x) + 1, 1000) ;
plot(x,y,'.',X,f(X))
```

Edit

Sorry, I'm using Matlab. Looking at the Octave documentation. You should be able to get the coefficients using

```
p = polyfit(x,y,length(y)-1)';
```

Then to display the coefficients the way you specified try this

```
strcat(cellstr(char(96+(1:length(p))')), { ' = ' } , cellstr(num2str(p)))
```

Comment: Hello @user1543042 and thank you for your reply. That is correct, I have changed the value. I have tried what you have written and have received this.

```
error: 'fit' undefined near line 21 column 3
error: called from
code at line 21 column 2
```

How would I be able to have it generalised in the sense that I can do

```print(
a=
b=
c=
d=
e=
)```

Regardless of what polynomial i choose the quartic to be

Comment: I am using octave ***

Comment: Thank you, I was able to base a solution off your edited response!

Answer (score 0):

```
y=[5 0 -1 2 9];
x=[-2 -1 0 1 2];
P=polyfit(x,y,2)
```

gives

```
P =
   2.0000   1.0000  -1.0000
```

these are your coefficients for c,d,e the others are zero. You can check the result:

```
polyval(P, x)

ans =
   5.0000e+00   2.2204e-16  -1.0000e+00   2.0000e+00   9.0000e+00
```

which gives you `y`

Btw, you can solve this very fast just inside your head without calculator because the function values for x=0 and x=+/-1 are very easy to calculate.

Comment: This is what I've written in my code.

```y=M(1,:);
x=M(2,:);
P=polyfit(x,y,2);
p=polyval(P, x);
a = p(1);
b = p(2);
c = p(3);
d = p(4);
e = p(5);``` Can you clarify that this is correct ?